# How to run function from external file as action for form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Description:**

At present I have html file with a form like the following:

```
<form id="my_form" action="javascript:OnAction()" method='post' >
</form>
```

I have javascript function "OnAction()" in external file like script.js.

**Problem:**

OnAction() function isn't run, if it is located in external file (In html this function is runned).
Other scripts in external file are runned (It means that script file is connected correctly).

**Question:**

How I can run OnAction() function on action of my form and hold it in external file?

Is exists way to bind something like:

```
$('#my_form').on('action', function() {
    // OnAction here
});
```

Comment: `action` is URI of the server script handling form submission. Form submit event is called `onsubmit`. So you need `<form onsubmit="OnAction()">`

Answer (score 2):

Change your HTML to:

```
<form id="my_form" action="" onSubmit="OnAction()" method='post'></form>
```

You just need to do this:

```
function OnAction() {
    // OnAction here
};
```

Or better way is to put your event with Jquery:

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form" action="" method='post'></form>
```

JS:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function() {
    /* OnAction here*/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_form').on('action', function() {
```

The event that fires when a a form is submitted is `submit` not `action`. Use that (with a real URL in the action with a server side fallback in case the JS fails; don't forget to `preventDefault()`).

Answer (score 0):

Add reference of your external file to your HTML file.

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML:

```
...
<form method="post" id="myform">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script src="abc.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
```

In your js. file:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myform");
elem.addEventListener("submit", function() {
   //
},false);
```

Comment: because not enough jquery