# How do I initialize JavaScript using the form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to initialize my var from HTML to my JavaScript file but my form is not working.if i initialize by myself the function is working but when initialize  from HTML not working.
i test any thing comes to my mind but it is not working.

```js
function DDA() {
    var x1, x2, y1, y2 ,m;
    x1=document.getElementById('x1').value;
    x2=document.getElementById('x2').value;
    y1=document.getElementById('y1').value;
    y2=document.getElementById('y2').value;
    if(x1==null||x1==""||x2==null||x2==""||y1==null||y1==""||y2==null||y2==""){
        console.log('enter number');
        return false;
    }
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    console.log(`(${x1},${y1})`);
    if (m > 1) {
        for (var i = y1 + 1; i <= y2; i++) {
            x1 = (x1 + (1 / m));
            console.log(`(${Math.round(x1)},${i})`);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = x1 + 1; i <= x2; i++) {
            y1 = (y1 + m);
            console.log(`(${i},${Math.round(y1)})`);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form  name="myform" onsubmit=" return (DDA())" action="index.html" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="x1" placeholder="x1"><br>
        <input type="text" id="x2" placeholder="x2"><br>
        <input type="text" id="y1" placeholder="y1"><br>
        <input type="text" id="y2" placeholder="y1"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitform" >
    </form>





    <script src="tamrin.js">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: text inputs can never have the value `null`. they are strings and are either empty or have some content.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working".
When I run that, it does output the numbers in the console when the input fields are filled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run function from external file as action for form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905541/how-to-run-function-from-external-file-as-action-for-form)

Comment: what do you mean `initialize my var from HTML`?Assuming you are expecting the form to cancel submit action do you see  the `"enter number"` in browser console?

Comment: I think form's are properly working .All fields are not null the form will be submited. but the page was refreshed.Use the `return false` in the end of the function also .It will be prevent the page refresh You will get the answer from `console log`

Comment: Sorry my English is not so good
i want read my number from form 
if i  value x y myself my function print numbers but i want read that number from form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code run perfectly If you fill all the text box it prints in the console if any filed not filled it show the message as "enter the number" because of your validation.